# Detect UIView animation and copy it

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewanimation, caanimation

I have two views. Lets call them `view1` and `view2`. They are at the same level in the views hierarchy. I want `view2` to always follow `view1` (both in position and size). I added some constraints to do that and it works fine. The problem is with the animations. Whenever I animate `view1` I want `view2` to do the same thing. Note that only `view1` is visible to the 'outside world', and only `view1` knows about `view2` so I cannot just add `view2` in the animations block. Can somehow `view2` copy the animations of `view1`?

EDIT:
`view1` is animated either by changing the frame or by changing constraints and `view2` should work in both cases.

```
- (void)addView2 {
    [self.superview insertSubview:self.view2 belowSubview:self];

    self.view2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.superview addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view2 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];
    [self.superview addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view2 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];
    [self.superview addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view2 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];
    [self.superview addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view2 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];
}
```

This is the relevant code from `view1`.

Animations:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:kAnimationDuration animations:^{
    view1.frame = some other frame;
}];
```

or

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:kAnimationDuration animations:^{
    [view1 layoutIfNeeded]
}];
```

Comment: How are the animations being done? If it's by changing the constraints of a view and then animating `layoutIfNeeded()` then your views should follow one another to satisfy their constraints.

Comment: Well this is supposed to be a generic solution, so it should work both by changing the frame or changing the constraints.

Comment: If you're working with constraints (in code at least) then you set `translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints` to false, specifically so that changing the frame does not make constraints. Basically it's best to use either constraints to move a view OR the frame to move a view.

Comment: You are right but if I chage the frame then the `layoutIfNeeded()` trick does not work anymore.

Comment: Set your view2 animation on completion of view1 animation.

Comment: @Mitesh Dobareeya as I said above `view2` is not visible outside `view1` so I cannot do that.

Comment: Try calling the `superview?.layoutIfNeeded()`

Comment: @ Andy Heard this is part of the problem. Where should I call it? How do I know that `view1` is performing an animation?

Comment: write necessary code that how you animating both views! and what constraints you have set?

Comment: @Jelly When you change the `view1` constraints and call `layoutIfNeeded()` on the superview, it should automatically update `view2` too as the constraints for both views are owned by the superview. If the `view2` constraints are set up correctly, then changing a `view1` constraint and calling `superview?.layoutIfNeeded()` will layout both views. You should only need to call it once to layout both views.

Comment: @Lion I added the relevant code. @Andy could you please provide an answer with an example? Note that I might not always call `layoutIfNeeded()` from the animation block.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know your animation code, I guess you are using autolayout so seems your animation act to the **frame** and not to the **constraints** involved. This can cause (to one or both view during animation) an ugly size distortion. Check your code and correct all animations by using constraints.

A simple example:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 1.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionNone, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.view1LeadingConstraint.constant = 30
        }, completion: { (finished: Bool) -> Void in
})
```

Comment: I edited my answer. The solution should work both by animating the constraints OR by animating the frame change.

Comment: If you using autolayout (in on), it required only a single element in your code that does not respect the constraints to destroy all the logic of constraints in your xib.

Comment: And always if you use autolayout (in on) only constraints modification can work well, any changing on the frame work but dont respect constraints..here is the issue

Comment: I don't have any autolayout issues. `view2` has center and size constraints equal to `view1`. That's all and when I animate `view1` I want `view2` to do the same thing.

Comment: There are multiple animation blocks both as the one you provided or as just `view1.frame = frame`

Answer (score 0):

Write `[self.view layoutIfNeeded];` before animating any view :

```
 for example,

 [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
 [UIView animateWithDuration:kAnimationDuration animations:^{
       view1.frame = some other frame;
 }];
```

You need to call `layoutIfNeeded` before animation it if you use autolayout and animating it by manipulating frames.

If it is not work then write `layoutIfNeeded` for other both `view` too and then animate

Hope this will help